# PLINQ and Large Data Searching

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing, plinq

I was looking for validation that what I'm thinking is an ideal solution.

I have a list of several million 'entities' coming from a customer.  I want to compare each entity to another (or several other) list/s that can have millions of entities, and record hits.

An entity is usually a person, with a name/number/date of birth/etc, but can be something like a business name.

I have a project that takes a request as one entity xml, searches, and saves the request and result xml into the database.

What I need is to run that project on a configurable number of threads, spawning new threads as others complete.  Is PLINQ an ideal solution to this?

So say I want 10 threads.  I want to take the first 10 entities and spawn 10 threads.  As the first thread ends, the 11th entity should start on a new thread, etc, till all have been searched.

Thankyou for any input, I'm not well-versed on parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be saving into a database anyway, why don't you just bulk import your data and use queries to join the two sets of data? That should perform much faster than trying to do it in memory. I would hate to see the memory you are consuming with millions of entities.

If you must do it in memory, using PLinq MAY prove to be faster. There is an overhead to thread creation and context switching. With PLinq, you should let the engine determine the thread allocations. You should rarely create threads explicitly at this point.

However, if the list you are comparing against is relatively static, you may benefit more from making it a dictionary and relying on the key for the lookup as you won't have to scan through the entire list for each item you are trying to find.